# Merging two parts of the vector into another vector using STL std::merge()

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

Have two vectors: `std::vector<int> collA{2,4,6,3,5,7}` & `std::vector<int> collB(collA.size())`, and I am trying to merge left half of `collA`(contains even numbers) with right side of `collA`(contains odd numbers) into `collB`:

```
std::merge(collA.cbegin(), std::next(collA.cbegin(), collA.size()/2 + 1), // left source 
    std::next(collA.cbegin(), collA.size()/2), collA.cend(),  // right source
    collB.begin()); // Output
```

However, `std::merge()` fails somewhere and Visual Studio 2012 gives me following error:

```
 ---------------------------
Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library
---------------------------
Debug Assertion Failed!

Program: C:\Windows\system32\MSVCP110D.dll
File: c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\algorithm
Line: 3102

Expression: sequence not ordered

For information on how your program can cause an assertion
failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.
```

Both Input ranges are sorted, so why am I getting this error ? 
(Note: VS2012 does not support C++11 initializer list syntax, I used to save some space)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Both Input ranges are sorted

No, this is not true. You could check that with

```
std::vector<int> collA{2,4,6,3,5,7};

std::copy(collA.cbegin(), std::next(collA.cbegin(), collA.size()/2 + 1),
            std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
std::cout << std::endl;
std::copy(std::next(collA.cbegin(), collA.size()/2), collA.cend(),
            std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
```

Output:

```
2 4 6 3 
3 5 7
```

You have to change last iterator for first sequence:

```
std::next(collA.cbegin(), collA.size()/2)
//                                     no + 1 here
```

Because size of `collA` is 6, and `collA.cbegin() + collA.size() / 2 + 1` is the same as `collA.cbegin() + 4` and points to `5`.

Comment: Got it, I miscalculated the ranges by one, and now I see why I did it. Funny part, I wrote exactly same code to make sure I am getting ranges, and still failed to perceive that `3` shouldn't be in `2 4 6 3`.